# Customize pluginButtonSmall Facebook

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I add the iframe like of FB in my Website and I want to customize the button. They are a class pluginButtonSmall in the source code.

I tried adding `

```
.pluginButton{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000!important;
  border: 1px solid #CAD4E7;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  color: #3B5998;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px 6px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

in my style.css but is not work! Why ?

Comment: Is this one of Facebook's own buttons? You can't modify these, they come in iframes.

Comment: yes this is the fb. My goal is to make [this model][1] but I do not know how


  [1]: http://touslespsd.com/boutons-de-partage-facebook-et-twitter-psd/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it via CSS. Because those buttons are displayed in iframes. However, you can create your own 3D buttons via Photoshop and point them to hyperlinks which fb has given to you.

Comment: Ok but here,How to integrate the counter?http://touslespsd.com/boutons-de-partage-facebook-et-twitter-psd/

Comment: It is not possible to do it via CSS. You must create your own buttons from Photoshop.

Comment: I understood that I had to create buttons with photoshop. But for functions like, what php code or another I have to for the counter like? sorry for my english